# Lightning UI Date field validation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have two fields `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
I have to validate the fields and show error on lightning component.
`EndDate` field should not be greater than `StartDate`.

My Code:

```
        var startDateField = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
        var endDateField = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;

        if ((Date.parse(EndDate) <= Date.parse(StartDate))) {
            alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
            document.getElementById("EndDate").value = "";
        }
```

Getting below Error:

> Uncaught Action failed:  [Cannot read property 'value' of null]

Comment: please confirm that you have element with Id "end" available .

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. You're not referencing the correct variable names...you have **startDateField** and **endDateField** defined as variable names, but your if statement is attempting to evaluate variables named **EndDate** and **StartDate** - these variables are not defined.
2. In general, rather than using document.getElementById(), use the aura:id attribute when defining your HTML elements to establish a local ID, and then reference that local ID using component.find().
   Reference: [Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm)